# Kalman filter for acceleremoter and gyro

Tags: data-analysis, bayesian-network, kalman-filter

I have read a lot of literature on this topic, but many questions still remain.

(Many formulae are here below, so, who prefers to look at them in a more comfortable manner can find a MathCAD sheet link in the end of the post).

So, we have a truck with an accelerometer and gyroscope. The following filter was obtained:

status vector X(6x1):

```
|x| - coordinate on the axis Х 
|y| - coordinate on the axis Y 
|φ| - robot turning angle 
|V| - robot linear velocity
|ω| - robot angular velocity
|a| - robot tangent acceleration
```

observation matrix Y(2x1):

```
|ya| - data from accelerometer
|yg| - data from gyroscope
```

the system model (t — time step):

```
x = x + cos(φ) * (V * t + a * t^2/2)
y = y + sin(φ) * (V * t + a * t^2/2)
φ = φ + ω * t
V = V + a * t
ω = ω
a = a
```

matrix F(6x6):

```
|1  0  -sin(φ)*(a*t^2 / 2+V*t)  t*cos(φ)  0 t^2 *cos(φ)/2|
|0  1  cos(φ)*(a*t^2 / 2+V*t)   t*cos(φ)  0 t^2 *sin(φ)/2|
|0  0          1               0      t        0     |
|0  0          0               1      0        t     |
|0  0          0               0      t        0     |
|0  0          0               0      0        t     |
```

matrix H(2x6):

```
|0  0  0  0  0  1|
|0  0  0  0  1  0|
```

matrix I(6x6) — identity
matrix N(2x2) — identity
matrix V(2x2) — identity
matrix R(2x2) — identity
matrix W(2x2) — identity

matrix Q(6x6): — I composed it empirically, tried to compute using a random sample, its variance for the diagonal items and covariance for all the rests

matrix P(6x6) — equals Q at the beginning

[xT] — transposed matrix, (x[-1]) — inverse matrix

the filter:

```
K = P*[HT] ((HP[HT] + VR[VT])[-1])
P=(I — KH)P
x = x + K(y — h(x))
P=FP[FT] + WQ[WT]
x = f(x,y)
```

I obtained diagrams for [acceleration and turning angle](http://habrastorage.org/storage2/e21/820/061/e218200614e828d8ecc9cb9be7cc0ad7.png). The acceleration diagram looks like it is to be, but the turning angle one is absolutely wrong. It was noticed, the matrix Q influences the filter strongly.

So, I have two questions:
1) did I compose the filter in right manner (if I had mistaken, please, let me know where);
2) how the matrix Q should be computed? (I even tried such a way: selected it empirically, and it worked very well, but I changed the system behaviour - acceleration - and the filter became incorrect).

All the calculations are in the [MathCAD sheet](http://habrastorage.org/storage2/1d5/95d/303/1d595d303d73b313f8534c32fd345dc4.png).

Comment: Wrong kind of [filters]. :-)

Comment: can you explain?

Comment: If you bothered reading the excerpt of the [filters] tag, describing the sort of questions fitting that tag, you would know.

Answer (score 1):

The common Kalman filter is linear. Your model is not linear (it has `sin`/`cos` functions and multiplication). So, you cannot use the common Kalman filters. There are variations for non-linear models, but they're more complex.